# AngularJS get data from service URL

Tags: angularjs

I am new in AngularJS.
I download AngularJS theme from URL [here](https://startangular.com/product/flatlogic-angular-material-dashboard/)

I have to get Data from GET Service.
GET Service URL is given below

> http://localhost:8080/api/getHostStatus

that is running correctly.

So I have to use this URL and get data from that service for this I just change the code in my **VisitorsController.js**
VisitorsController.js file code is given below

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('VisitorsController', [
            VisitorsController
        ]);

    function VisitorsController() {
        var vm = this;
        // TODO: move data to the service
        var servicesUrl = app.serviceCallUrl+'getHostStatus';
        console.log(servicesUrl);
        var myService = angular.module("app").factory("myService", ['$http', function($http) {
            return {
                getResponders: (function(response) {
                    return $http.get(servicesUrl).then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        return response.data;
                    });
                })()
            };
            return myService;
        }]);

        vm.visitorsChartData = [ {key: 'UP', y: 5264}, { key: 'Critical', y: 3872},{key: 'Warning', y: 1000} ];

        vm.chartOptions = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pieChart',
                height: 210,
                donut: true,
                x: function (d) { return d.key; },
                y: function (d) { return d.y; },
                valueFormat: (d3.format(".0f")),
                color: ['rgb(0, 150, 136)', '#E75753','#fbbc05'],
                showLabels: false,
                showLegend: false,
                title: 'Over 9K',
                margin: { top: -10 }
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

When I run this it is showing me correct `servicesUrl` on console.
But `response.data` not showing on console.

So please guide me how can I resolve it.

Comment: Did you try `response.json().data`?

Comment: Write a `service` as separate function and inject in `controller`, then try to use.

Comment: @RVP I try this but no progress.

Comment: @AvneshShakya So should I create new file app.service?

Comment: so if you just try to output the whole response object, what does it show?

Comment: @RVP It showing me only servicesUrl in my console after that nothing

Comment: @RVP It is showing me "Error: transition superseded at $StateProvider.$get" is that a case of issue?

Comment: Ok I may be blind but are you actually calling the method you've defined? Like running `myService.getResponders()`?

Comment: @RVP You mean to say that I have to create getResponders method right?

Comment: You've already created it - look at the answer that the guy below submitted. That's what I meant.

Comment: Also, just a friendly word of advice, if you are new to AngularJS don't waste your time learning Angular because it will soon be deprecated.Learn Angular2 and start using Angular CLI - it makes life a lot easier.

Comment: You need to help yourself, I had to delete the answer as you are not learning.